# Uploading CSV with multiple columns into SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, export-to-csv

I have data that was originally in an .xls file that had to be put into a .csv file. I am trying to upload to sql to create a database, but I have separate columns in my .csv file. How can I preserve my columns without the commas automatically creating new columns after uploading and making a mess out of it? Thanks.

Comment: can you a sample (one or two lines) of your csv file? another question: can you process your CSV using a programming language (PHP, Java, C#...) or in your case it has to be done directly by the database?

Comment: CSV files don't have columns, they store plain text. What do you mean by "column" in this context?

Answer (score 0):

How ever the CSV was exported if it didn't properly escape commas embedded in fields then you are basically hosed.  I would try to go back to the original source file and do the conversion with a tool that will properly quote the fields.

Answer (score 0):

We found out the issue was that we were not allocating enough space for the columns (too many characters). The .csv file has 30k+ rows so we missed some that had a lot of characters. Simple mistake.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Massimiliano - Actually, this is the OP answering his own question.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher As it stands it seems to me more a comment to the other answer.